# Dividing a country, geographically, into equidistant points (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to split the map of panama into equidistant lat,long coordinates and am using numpy, to create the linspace that will separate them out, based off the lat longs at the bottomLeft, bottomRight, topLeft, and topRight of the map. To do so I'm using a nested for loop.

The problem is that, despite getting the correct number of unique latitudes in the final dictionary, I'm only getting one unique longitude. Can you help me correct the mistake in the loop so that the final dictionary tfed into the final dataframe gives 646 in response to

```
grid_centroid.long.nunique()
```

Thanks a bunch!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bottomLeft = (7.239013, -82.94546842973114)
bottomRight = (7.239013, -77.177479)
topLeft = (9.62079503922844, -82.94546842973114)
topRight = (9.62079503922844, -77.177479)

df = pd.read_csv('sites_unique.csv')


cols = np.linspace(bottomLeft[1], bottomRight[1], num=276)
rows = np.linspace(bottomLeft[0], topLeft[0], num=646)
df['col'] = np.searchsorted(cols, df['Average of lat'], 'right')
df['row'] = np.searchsorted(rows, df['Average of long'], 'right')

grid_dict = {'lat':[],'long':[]}

for l in range(275):
    lat_index_init = l
    for i in range(645):
        lon_init_index = i
        grid_dict['lat'].append(rows[lat_index_init])
        grid_dict['long'].append(cols[lon_index_init])            
        i + 1        
    l + 1
    i = 0

grid_centroid = pd.DataFrame(grid_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

quick fix, figured it out and it was acutally very simple

```
bottomLeft = (7.239013, -82.94546842973114)
bottomRight = (7.239013, -77.177479)
topLeft = (9.62079503922844, -82.94546842973114)
topRight = (9.62079503922844, -77.177479)

cols = np.linspace(bottomLeft[1], bottomRight[1], num=646)
rows = np.linspace(bottomLeft[0], topLeft[0], num=275)

grid_dict = {'lat':[],'long':[]}

for l in range(275):
    lat_index_init = l
    for i in range(645):
        grid_dict['lat'].append(rows[l])
        grid_dict['long'].append(cols[i])            
        i + 1        
    l + 1
    i = 0
```

produces the desired result. I hope this helps out other people struglling to create geospatial grids

All the best